# How can I use a previous button c#

Tags: c#

I can't seem to get this line to work properly in this code so it wont break:
`Course currentCourse = courseList[indexForInfoList];`
When I first run the form and click previous the code will break, when I click Next a couple times then previous it works fine, I don't know how to write the code so I can continuously hit previous- any ideas out there? :)

```
    private void loadPreviousCourse()
    {
        //get count of elements from array
        int countOfCourses = courseList.Count;
       
        if (countOfCourses > 0)
        {
            indexForInfoList--;

            if (indexForInfoList >= countOfCourses)
                indexForInfoList = -1;

            Course currentCourse = courseList[indexForInfoList];


            textBoxCourseNumber.Text = currentCourse.courseNumber.ToString();
            textBoxCourseName.Text = currentCourse.courseName;
            textBoxCourseCredits.Text = currentCourse.numberOfCredits.ToString();
            textBoxGrade.Text = currentCourse.grade;

        }
        
    }
```

Comment: You get any error message? An `IndexOutOfBounds` exception probably? When you start your code, `indexForInfoList` is probalby `0`. Then when you click the "Previous" button, it gets decremented, ie it becomes `-1`.  And then you try to access `courseList[-1]`. You see the error?

Comment: Also this part  `if (indexForInfoList >= countOfCourses) indexForInfoList = -1;` is quite dangerous. Ie if you click "Next" too often, it will also throw an exception ...

Comment: You might want to take into account the case where `countOfCourses <= 0` for your GUI. If you don't reach a break, it's because of the condition (`if`). Eventually check out "guard pattern".

Comment: Is this `ASP.NET`, `Blazor`, `WinForms`,  `WPF` or what framework this is under? Please [edit] question and add appropriate tags.

Comment: What is your expected behaviour when you reach the beginning of the list? Roll over to the end? Do nothing? What is your expected behaviour when you reach the end of the list? Roll over to the beginning? Do nothing?

Comment: This is ASP.NET - and yes I do get the index out of bounds exception message. I see how it doesn't want to go to -1 because it is out of bounds but how would I code this to be able to click previous and start from the end of that array so there is no error?

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, you want to wrap over if you reach either end of the list, ie got to the last item once you reach the beginning of the list and vice versa. This can be achieved as follows

```
private void getCourse(int direction) {
  if (courseList.Count > 0) {
    indexForInfoList += direction;
    
    //this will wrap over to the end if you walked past the beginning of the list
    if (indexForInfoList < 0) indexForInfoList = courseList.Count -1;
    //this will wrap over to the beginning if you walked past the end of the list
    else if (indexForInfoList >= courseList.Count) indexForInfoList  = 0;

    Course currentCourse = courseList[indexForInfoList];
    ...
  }
}
```

`direction` is either `+1` (for next) or `-1` (for previous). Now in your eventhandlers for the "Previous" and "Next" button, you can just call `getCourse(-1)` for previous and `getCourse(+1)` for next.

To make sure, your stepsize is always exactly `1` (because you could call it with `getCourse(10)` which would skip `9` courses) you can also use

```
indexForInfoList += Math.Sign(direction);
```